# How do I design a validation rule for a Microsoft Access field that restricts input to characters from specific Unicode ranges?

Tags: vba, validation, ms-access, unicode, expression

Suppose I needed to restrict a field to 1 character from the [Hangul Jamo Extended-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Jamo_Extended-A) range (U+A960–U+A97f), how would I compare the code of the character against the range? My validation fails for characters in that range as it’s written:

```
Len([C])=1 And AscW([C]) Between 43360 And 43391
```

Though this non-working example looks simple, I may have to replace `[C]` with more complex expressions, and so the simplicity of `AscW` with the `Between` operator is handy to avoid repeating `[C]`.

Answer (score 1):

`AscW` returns signed 16-bit integers, so the `Between` expression will always return `False` since the integers being compared are out of that type’s range (-32,768 to 32,767). Use the [two’s complement](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/twos-complement) of any values greater than 32,767. In your case, `43360` becomes `-22176` and `43391` becomes `-22145`.

```
Len([C])=1 And AscW([C]) Between -22176 And -22145
```

When `[C] = "ꥼ"`, `AscW([C])` will return `-22148` which will cause the entire expression to evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use character numbers when creating a field validation rule. Just test if the character is within the desired range by specifying the upper and lower limit:

```
Len([C])=1 And [C] Between "ꥠ" And "ꥼ"
```

Note that this uses the database sort order, so you want to make sure that's set to an appropriate sort order and not *General (legacy)* which can cause issues with unicode characters.